# Show the Image of the selected Image Texture Node in Image Editor

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, image

I dug up this old post about a CMYK-ish shader:
[Blender halftone pattern filter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102352/blender-halftone-pattern-filter)

In the blend file you can load from there, you find that whenever you select an Image Texture Node the image will show up in the Image Editor view. I really like that behavior and want to use it in my own files but can't find the settings for that. The blend file does not contain any scrips as well.

I found a [feature request](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/6dgbbc/?sorting=hot) on Right-Click-Select, which confused me a lot because - is that not a feature? and if it's not, why is it in this stackexchange project?

Can anybody help? (or suggest an Addon? :D)

obligatory apology in advance if I missed something obvious.

Comment: Hi :). It works just like you described in Blender 3.1. Are you sure you don't have an image *pinned*?

Comment: That seems to be an option in the built-in Amaranth toolset addon although I've never tried it. The docs at https://pablovazquez.art/amaranth/ are pretty old, but it's mentioned under the Nodes Editor heading.

Comment: Ok, so as mentioned, this seems to be a default behavior in Blender.. 
In my case it started to work after i added a new empty image texture node in the Shader Editor. When I selected my original Image Node the corresponding image showed up in the Editor. 
When I select another image in the Editor and then select the Node, the image does not change to the one of the node tho. Is that the usual behavior? I am not sure if i think it makes sense to keep the manually selected image or if it feels like a bug :D

Comment: Hi :). Yes that's expected behavior. You can open multiple image editors side by side :)